# More efficient way to collect unique attributes from an array of arrays

Tags: ruby

given a data structure as follows:

```
[ 
  [
    "1", 
    {
      :user_uid=>"1", 
      :display_name=>"joe", 
      :country_code=>"ITA", 
      # more attributes
    }
  ],
  # more users
]
```

I can get a unique list of all the `country_code` attributes like this:

```
users.map do |uid, attributes|
  attributes[:country_code]
end.uniq
```

but if I have a very large dataset, this still loops through every user (As Ajedi32 pointed out, of course that's the case).

Is there a more efficient way to collect this data?

Comment: you can use `uniq` with a block, but that's probably the best you can get given that it's already O(n)

Comment: You said "this still loops through every user", implying that you think there is a way of doing this without looping through every user. Given that any given user could potentially contain a new, unique country code, what makes you think it would be possible to do this without checking the country code of every user?

Comment: that's true, thanks for pointing for that out.  my faulty understanding aside, I would still like to find a more efficient way to harvest this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 1 user, I found the following to be faster than `uniq` when I compared the time it took each method to run 500 times. Could help you.

```
begin
  array = []

  users.each do |_, attributes|
    array |= [attributes[:country_code]]
    # http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C
  end

  array
end
```

Comment: @Зелёный that's [`Array#|`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
 require 'set`

 users.each_with_object(Set.new) { |(_, attributes),s|
     s <<  attributes[:country_code]  }.to_a
```